# Running a python script using local python interpreter and not QGIS python interpreter

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have my custom-built plugin for QGIS3.32

**What I want to achieve is :**
If I click a QPushButton on my plugin, the function to which the button is connected to should run in my local python interpreter and not the QGIS python interpreter as its a heavy computing function. Also so that QGIS doesn't go in 'not responding' mode(dont know why does QGIS go in not responding mode and how to avoid it).
***Note :*** The python script which I want to run has no PyQgis libraries in it. Its just some vigorous matrix multiplication which I want to do.

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: I would suggest using the [QgsTask](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsTask.html) class. https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html